# Hyperledger Composer: data exchange between two participants

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

Please consider the scenario below:

1. Participant A calls a TP and creates an asset XYZ.
2. Now, A also wants to tell participant B the unique id of the asset that he created.

Should A emit an event with the asset id? But I read that events are subscribed by node.js applications. Is there some way for B to get the id?

Assuming that the asset id that A created is the same as the transaction id, can B read the transaction registry and get that information? I tried to do this, but I got an error:

`var tReg = await getTransactionRegistry('org.acme.sample.SampleTransaction');`

But the composer playground gave an error that `getTransactionRegistry()` is not defined.

---EDIT--

Actually, `getTransactionRegistry()` will not work, because to get a particular transaction, I need the id first.

Answer (score 0):

`getTransactionRegistry` is a global function in chaincode. Do you call it from your client application? In that case, you should write smth like `connection.getTransactionRegistry`.

Comment: My comment is too long, so I'm submitting it as a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when you create an asset, you should give it a unique ID manually. In addition, you won't have the asset in the registry until the transaction is submitted.

You are correct that events are subscribed by the client code. And this is the preferred way to notify another client of new assets. So, instead of looking up the transaction ID, you should subscribe to the event that you emit in your transaction code.

For example, your client app invokes a transaction that adds an asset to a registry and emits the corresponding event. Another company runs their own client app that listens to events. As soon as the transaction is processed, they are notified of the new asset.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to deal with it would not be related to events.

You will simply create an asset Registry call it `MyAsset` and then have another register called `AssetListing`, this asset listing can then have reference to your asset which will be created if you execute a transaction on it call that transaction `ListMyAsset`:

```
participant Person identified by personId {
  o String personId
  o String fullName
}

asset MyAsset identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o String assetName
}

asset AssetListing identified by listingId {
  o String listingId
  o Integer assetPrice
  --> MyAsset asset
}

transaction ListMyAsset {
  --> MyAsset asset
  o Integer assetPrice
}
```

Then you can define your transaction which will take asset and price and create another asset/resource in your AssetListing registery.

Next you should define your ACL rules that will allow owner participants to have access to MyAsset registery over their own assets and AssetListing will be available to all participants, if you don't want AssetListing to be available you can update its model and add a sharedWithParticipant relation that can help you write even more specific ACL rules.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I understand your design, but I don't see how Person A can tell Person B that an asset has been created. Simply writing it into a list doesn't inform Person B.

Comment: I haven't personally reached that point will update answer if I get it done